# Google DataStore - Too much contention with batch save

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have this simple structure

```
ParentEntity 
   => ChildEntity
```

I put 20K child entities in a single save like this

```
ofy().save().entities(childEntities).now()
```

But it fails with too much contention, however it works with 10K-14K entities.
I can't find which limit it's hitting, see [Limits page](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Limits page you have mentioned states that -

> **Maximum write rate to an entity group - 1 per second**
>
> Note you can batch writes together for an entity group. This allows
>   you to write multiple entities to an entity group within this limit.

The same page also indicates that max entities per commit/write is 500. If all 20,000 entities are children of a single parent (entity group), your write speed is limited as stated above. Try splitting the writes to less than or equal to 500 entities per batch and add a slight delay (1 sec) between each batch.

Comment: If all 20k entities are in a single entity group, the best thing to do is start a transaction and write it in that txn. You won't need to add any delays.

Comment: @stickfigure - when I try this with the new google-cloud API, it still fails to commit a transaction when the total entities in the transaction are more than 500. The error I get is - cannot write more than 500 entities in a single call, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT. Does this work differently using Objectfy/underlying AppEngine Datastore API?

Comment: Using Objectify, I can write around 10K entity with single call.

Comment: @stickfigure You can't add 20K in a single transaction because the transaction size would be too much and the call fails.